# Does viber share my personal info with third parties

Tags: encryption, privacy, viber

Does viber share our personal information with third parties?
What includes in the personal information as they mention in their privacy policy? Is it just name contact number and email only... or also the messages that we send to each other and media ?
For what reason they share our information with such parties? And what is the encryption that they use?

Comment: Only viber knows what and who they share with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vibers Privacy policy is [here](http://www.viber.com/en/privacypolicy_m.html).

From this I get that -

- Among other things they will leak which of your contacts use Viber, and leak that you use Viber to them.
- Disclose your Viber number to whoever wants it "they do not consider the fact that your Viber number exists on viber as private information"
- Viber will share your name and photo with other parties, as well as your online status, the last time you connected and and if you have seen messages sent to you.
- If you use billable servers, Viber will pass details on to those parties so they can bill you and provide other requested services.
- They will allow other companies to track you on there behalf - ie use other companies for analytics - including Google Analytics which provides some detail about your usage habits to Google.
- They will give up your information if required to by law.

Viber does use encryption, although the encryption method is not easily come by.  They also have had issues with being hacked and leaving some data unencrypted.

Comment: Yes... my photo means the photo that I use for like my profile picture right? Not the photos I sent or recieved right?

Comment: According to the privacy policy that is correct.

Comment: Okay thanks alot but by the encryption are they able to decrypt the messages we send and recieved?

Comment: My guess would be yes - but its only a guess.  From the questions you are asking you want to educate yourself about CALEA (This is US law which pretty much requires US Telcos to add a back door so the government can listen in on conversations.  This may or may not apply here - Viber is based outside the USA, but I'm guessing it has ties to America and may be required to do so.

Comment: Also read the "Security" link at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viber - According to the EFF, Viber does not do very well - specifically they can decrypt encrypted communication, and there are issues with there implementation of encryption.

Comment: But they say that photos are not stored in servrrs for much longer getting deleted within seconds once they uploaded into yheir sercers... can we ask them not to share anything of our communication to any parties since it has my very personal data...

Comment: @Jason - The image are stored on the Viber servers.  No; You can't ask them not to share your communication, you already agreed they could share your communicate, when you created your account.

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean by communication. is it just my address book data or my name or my email? or even my messsages and photos sent through viber?

Comment: Everything per the terms you agreed to